# Distribution upgrade freezes

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, upgrade

When upgrading from Ubuntu 10.04 to 10.10 the distribution upgrade program freezes after it notifies me of a change in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.mysqld` and asks me to keep the old file or accept the new changes (I accepted them).

The terminal says:

```
Configuration file `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** usr.sbin.mysqld (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? y
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld ...
```

The program hasn't done anything after this for about 2 hours now and I have no idea what I should do at this point. Can I quit the program and restart it? Or is there another action I should take?

It did however change the '/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld' to the new version, but is still frozen...

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this error while upgrading from 10.04 to 10.10. However, AppArmor was not installed. Therefore, the following fixed the problem for me:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

After running this command from a separate SSH session, the upgrade continued.

Answer (score 1):

that was very useful.
I had to use this command though to restart the upgrade

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor teardown
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but with cups, that is the upgrade was hanging on upgrading cups (had been 32 minutes remaining for an hour and a half).

To solve the problem I did this (in a terminal)

```
sudo service cups stop
```

and the upgrade continued (and is running now as I write this).

Answer (score 0):

Try first to stop Apparmor with the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor stop
```